# ATI videocard not recognized

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, ati-mobility-radeon

I have a laptop with win7 and a ATI Radeon 6370M graphics adapter which is not recognized by the ATI installation program. Is there a way to download specific drivers for this card and force the installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turnes out I was dealing with a rebranded Ati Radeon 6370M chip. I found the correct drivers through a custom Catalyst created by Acer, available [here](http://www.geeks3d.com/forums/index.php/topic,1822.0.html)

Answer (score 2):

When you're installing drivers for a laptop graphics chip, it's best to get the laptop manufacturer's drivers. The reason being they are quite often optimised for use with the mainboard & display.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the ATI site, you should be able to find the drivers for that.

I would also doing an overall Windows Update. It would worth a try as well.

Comment: Catalyst does not recognize the graphic card at all...